# Document expired when click on back button

Tags: zend-framework, backspace

When I press ob backspace button for website I make using zend framework, the error page that

```
Confirm Form Resubmission
```

occur, how can I know what data I should resend when I press on back button ? I have many pages with many data !

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is a normal behavior of your browser, IMO, the best you can do is prevent the browser to send the data again, but you can't choose what data to send.

How to prevent the browser to send the `$_POST` data again?

You need to redirect the user to the same page after your post request:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller', 'module');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error/popup because you are trying repeat a POST request in your browser. The browser is warning you so you don't create unwanted duplicate posts. You will get this when you submit a form, then attempt to go back a page.

If you are building a web application and your intention was to repost the same data again, just confirm the resubmission to repeat the request.